Question about step in proof for Mobius inversion formula
I came across this proof found in chapter 6.2 from Elementary Number Theory by David M. Burton, 7e and I am confused by one of the steps. Here is the theorem and proof as presented in the book:
Theorem 6.7 - Mobius inversion formula. Let $F$ and $f$ be two number-theoretic functions related by the formula:
$$F(n) = \sum_{d|n}{f(d)}$$
Then,
$$f(n) = \sum_{d|n}\mu(d)F\left(\frac{n}{d}\right) = \sum_{d|n}\mu\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)F(d)$$
Proof. The two sums mentioned in the conclusion of the theorem are seen to be the same upon replacing the dummy index $d$ by $d′ = \frac{n}{d}$; as $d$ ranges over all positive divisors of n, so does $d'$.
Carrying out the required computation, we get
$$(1) \sum_{d|n}\mu(d)F\left(\frac{n}{d}\right) = \sum_{d|n}\left(\mu(d)\sum_{c|(n/d)}{f\left(c\right)}\right) = \sum_{d|n}\left(\sum_{c|(n/d)}{\mu(d)f\left(c\right)}\right)$$
It is easily verified that $d|n$ and $c|(n/d)$ iff $c|n$ and $d|(n/c)$. Because of this, the last expression in Eq. (1) becomes
$$(2) \sum_{d|n}\left(\sum_{c|(n/d)}{\mu(d)f\left(c\right)}\right) = \sum_{c|n}\left(\sum_{d|(n/c)}{f(c)\mu(d)}\right) = \sum_{c|n}\left(f(c)\sum_{d|(n/c)}{\mu(d)}\right)$$
The sum $\sum_{d|(n/c)}{\mu(d)}$ must vanish except when $\frac{n}{c} = 1$ (that is, when $n = c$), in which case it is equal to 1; the upshot is that the RHS of Eq. (2) simplifies to
$$\sum_{c|n}\left(f(c)\sum_{d|(n/c)}{\mu(d)}\right) = \sum_{c=n}{f(c)*1} = f(n)$$
giving us the stated result.
My question, which might be basic: From the fact that $d|n$ and $c|(n/d)$ iff $c|n$ and $d|(n/c)$ is true (which I understand), how does it follow that $$\sum_{d|n}\left(\sum_{c|(n/d)}{\mu(d)f\left(c\right)}\right) = \sum_{c|n}\left(\sum_{d|(n/c)}{f(c)\mu(d)}\right)$$
More specifically, it seems like there is a missing step. From the iff statement, I don't quite understand how we are justified in replacing the bounds in the sum so that the sum on the LHS is equal to the sum on the RHS. I've seen examples that show this to be true, but I'd prefer something more general
I've also seen other questions on here about parts of other proofs for the same theorem, but no questions about this particular proof. Any help or insight would be appreciated

I find it easier to figure out how to interchange the order of summation by writing it as a sum over pairs instead of a double sum.  So,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{d|n}\left(\sum_{c|(n/d)}{\mu(d)f\left(c\right)}\right) &= 
\sum_{\stackrel{c,d \in \mathbb{N}}{d|n \text{ and }c|(n/d)}}   {\mu(d)f\left(c\right)} \\ &= \sum_{\stackrel{c,d \in \mathbb{N}}{c|n \text{ and }d|(n/c)}}      {\mu(d)f\left(c\right)} \\ &= \sum_{c|n}\left(\sum_{d|(n/c)}{f(c)\mu(d)}\right).
\end{align*}
Then it's clear why the second equality holds: it's a sum over the same set, written in a different way.
We could also write this using the indicator function $1_{P}$ which is equal to $1$ when the predicate $P$ is true, otherwise $0$.
We have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{d|n}\left(\sum_{c|(n/d)}{\mu(d)f\left(c\right)}\right) &= 
\sum_{c,d \in \mathbb{N}}   {\mu(d)f\left(c\right)} 1_{d|n \text{ and }c|(n/d)} \\ &= 
\sum_{c,d \in \mathbb{N}}   {\mu(d)f\left(c\right)} 1_{c|n \text{ and }d|(n/c)} \\ &= \sum_{c|n}\left(\sum_{d|(n/c)}{f(c)\mu(d)}\right).
\end{align*}
